# The question is about the timeline of the Mahabharata war in which Krishna summons Vishwakarma...?

Tags: krishna, indra, pandavas, vishwakarma

The question I have is about the timeline in which Krishna summons Vishwakarma to make the city of Indraprastha for the Pandavas; so, did this occur after the Mahabharata war? Or did that take place before the war?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's Maya, architect of Danavas and not Vishwakarma, architect of Devas. ([Ref1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01210.htm), [Ref2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02001.htm))

This took place before Mahabharata war. After Maya built Sabha Bhavan in Indraprastha, below are the major events before Mahabharata war:

- Arjuna went for 12 years exile ([Ref](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01216.htm))
- Pandavas go for Dikvijaya and Rajsuya Yajna ([Ref](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02025.htm))
- Pandavas went for 13 years exile ([Ref](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02075.htm))